# How to convert matlab function 'pchip' to c code with matlab coder

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-coder

I have a problem with Matlab Coder. I would like to generate C code from Matlab interpolating function `pchip`. I verified the function with `coder.screener` and it says it's available for code generation but when I try to build `pchip.m` file I get this error:

> The function 'pchip' is not supported for standalone code generation. See the documentation for coder.extrinsic to learn how you can use this function in simulation.

Can anyone help me? I really need to convert this function in C for a program I am writing.

Answer (score 1):

Limitations of `pp = pchip(x,y)` for code generation from the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html):

- Input `x` must be strictly increasing.
- Does not remove `y` entries with `NaN` values.
- If you generate code for the `pp = pchip(x,y)` syntax, you cannot input `pp` to the `ppval` function in MATLAB. To create a MATLAB `pp` structure from a `pp` structure created by the code generation software:

  - In code generation, use [`unmkpp`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/unmkpp.html) to return the piecewise polynomial details to MATLAB.
  - In MATLAB, use [`mkpp`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/mkpp.html) to create the `pp` structure.

So, please check that you fulfill the previous points; especially the last one. You have examples in the documentation of how to make/unmake a picewise polynomial.

Comment: Code generation support for `pchip` was added in R2014a http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/release-notes.html so if you are using a release before that you may consider upgrading.

Comment: Thank you very much libill39 that was it! The solution was upgrading to r2014.